# Downloading an image that is hotlink protected

Tags: curl

I would like to download an image that is hotlink protected. How can I forge the HTTP header with CURL to say the referer is coming from its own server?

I have tried with this command but it fails. I'm not familiar with PHP and help would be much apreciated.

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -L -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c -s 'http://remote-site.com/image.jpg' > image.jpg
```

Option looks to be `CURLOPT_REFERER` with `curl_setopt`, or `curl --referer` but not sure about the correct syntax.

---

EDIT 2 :

I got an error saying that curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long. After removing the MUTE option the error is gone.

To show the image I have tried this code but the page remains blank.

```
$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
print '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
```

---

EDIT 1:

The code I have entered in my Wordpress post (I use the plugin [Insert PHP](http://www.willmaster.com/software/WPplugins/insert-php-wordpress-plugin-instructions.php))

```
[insert_php]

curl --referer http://www.DOMAIN.com/ -A "Mozilla/5.0" -L -b /tmp -c /tmp -s 'http://www.DOMAIN.com/image.png' > image.png

[/insert_php]
```

The error I have when I load the page :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘<‘ in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(48) : eval()’d code on line 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the referer as an option to `curl` as follows:

```
curl --referer http://remote-site.com/ -A "Mozilla/5.0" -L -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c -s 'http://remote-site.com/image.jpg' > image.jpg
```

The syntax of curl is simply:

```
curl [options...] <url>
```

Just noticed: since you have specified silent mode with `-s`, you should specify output file with `--output <file>` parameter. With `-s` option you cannot use output redirection (`> image.jpg`) since there is no output to begin with.

Update:

You have to insert PHP code between the `[insert_php]` and `[/insert_php]` tags. The string you're having there right now is not valid PHP code. You have to use the `curl_*` functions provided by PHP. Your code should look something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen("image.jpg", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://remote-site.com/image.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/c");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/c");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://remote-site.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```